# AppInsights to monitorize Application Services

Tags: azure-application-insights

Currently we are using AppInsights to monitorize our .net applications.

Main problem is that similar products are relased with plugins in order to monitorize other kind of services installed on Premise Machines, Virtualized Machines...  i.e:

- SQL DataBases
- Redis Instances
- Docker containers
- ...

We are trying to understand how to accomplish it with AppInsights, if necessary developing these plugins... but we do not know what is the best approach or if we can get it using AppInsights.

Basically we want to use same Dashboard to analyze all kind of  metrics (Applications / Operations).. and not continue using n Dashboards (Zabbix, Nagios, Azure Portal Manager Dashboards...)

Any Idea?

Regards,

Oscar

Answer (score 1):

ApplicationInsights [collects](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-dependencies/) Sql and Http dependencies by default. 
Redis and docker are not supported but you can instrument your code using ApplicationInsights SDK.

Documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/

Sources: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for dependency tracking in applicationinsights. ( [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-dependencies](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-dependencies/)/ )